# Generate specific combinations of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools

I have 2 lists of differing length, say:

```
list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_b = ['x', 'y']
```

My desired output is all the unique combinations of list_b to list_a, for instance, there should be 16:

```
1. ['a', 'x', 'y']
2. [['a', 'x'], ['b', 'y']]
3. [['a', 'x'], ['c', 'y']]
4. [['a', 'x'], ['d', 'y']]
5. ['b', 'x', 'y']
6. [['b', 'x'], ['a', 'y']]
7. [['b', 'x'], ['c', 'y']]
8. [['b', 'x'], ['d', 'y']]
9. ['c', 'x', 'y']
10. [['c', 'x'], ['a', 'y']]
11. [['c', 'x'], ['b', 'y']]
12. [['c', 'x'], ['d', 'y']]
13. ['d', 'x', 'y']
14. [['d', 'x'], ['a', 'y']]
15. [['d', 'x'], ['b', 'y']]
16. [['d', 'x'], ['c', 'y']]
```

My guess of the number of total lists is len(list_a) ** len(list_b), so I understand the option space gets very big very quickly.

Any suggestions on an efficient way to do this in Python (avoiding generating excessive permutations and testing for duplicates etc)/

I've used itertools product, permutation, and combination on a lot of different list types and makeups. I can generate the required answer by using a loop to find all answers where each list_a has 2 entries from list_b (i.e. 1, 5, 9, 13 above) and then all the combinations where each list_a has 1 entry from list_b, but this method falls down once len(list_b) > 2.

EDIT:
This is a source/sink problem. list_b are sinks which all need to be used completely, list_a are the sources which can provide input to the sinks. i.e. for the problem above, all 3 sinks could be serviced by a single source (examples 1, 5, 9, 13), or could be split 1 source -> 2 sinks, or 1:1 in a bunch of ways - I'm trying to find all those ways

Comment: What is your desired output for a larger `list_b`? i.e with `list_b = ['x', 'y', 'z']` would the result for `a` be: `['a', 'x', 'y', 'z'], [['a', 'x'], ['b', 'y'], ['b', 'z']], [['a', 'x'], ['c', 'y'],  ['c', 'z']]
, [['a', 'x'], ['d', 'y'],  ['d', 'z']]`?

Comment: I can't figure out the general rule for the lists you want. It seems to me like items 1, 5, 9, 13 of your result are generated by one rule and the rest by a completely different rule. Also, if `[['d', 'x'], ['a', 'y']]` is allowed (using two elements from the first list in reverse order), then why not also, say, `[['a', 'y'], ['d', 'x']]` (using two elements from the *second* list in reverse order)?

Comment: Agree with above.  You need to edit your post and clearly define how you want to combine the lists.  Is it one from each?  Several from each?  What are the sub-lists you have in your result?  etc.

Comment: It's really a source/sink problem. list_b are sinks which all need to be used completely, list_a are the sources which can provide input to the sinks. i.e. for the problem above, all 3 sinks could be serviced by a single source (examples 1, 5, 9, 13), or could be split 1 source -> 2 sinks, or 1:1 in a bunch of ways - I'm trying to find all those ways

Comment: The word *functions* fits here much better than the word *combinations*. You apparently want to print all the functions from `list_b` to `list_a`, with each function represented as a list rather than as the usual dict. Your usage of *combinations* makes the problem look harder than it needs to be. The problem would also be easier if each line were a dict--then your purpose would be more clear and there need be no conversion from a dict in my answer to a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want a list of all *functions* from `list_b` to `list_a`, but you want each function to be represented in a particular list form rather than as the usual `dict` form or ordered pairs form. The word *functions* fits here much better than the word *combinations*.

Your format for your functions has two peculiarities. First, most of the lines in your example desired output are lists of lists. However, if the function that is represented has the image (the resulting items in `list_a`) as just one element of `list_a` you have a list rather than a list of lists. That works in your example where there are just two items in `list_b` so the range of the function is either only one item or all items of `list_a`. However, if `list_b` were larger, there will be cases where the range is neither one item nor all items of `list_a` and your desired result for that line is not clear.

Second, the order of your lines is not the best match for the usual ordering of such things.

Here is code that gives a list of lists for all the lines and has a slightly different ordering than you give. The basic idea is to get a function by lining up the items in the domain `list_b` in a fixed order, which is already done since the data structure is a list. Then take the *product* (in the itertools sense) of `list_a`, with `repeat=len(list_b)`, so that the first item in the product is the function result of the first item in `list_b`, and so on. The rest of the routine converts this defined function into a dictionary form of its inverse function, which groups each result item with all the domain items that map to it, then converts that to the list format that you show.

```
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict


def functions_as_lists(tolist, fromlist):
    """Return a list of functions from fromlist to tolist where each
    function is represented as a list of lists.
    """
    result = []
    for toitems in product(tolist, repeat=len(fromlist)):
        # Convert a tuple to a function represented as a dict
        afunction = defaultdict(list)
        for toitem, fromitem in zip(toitems, fromlist):
            afunction[toitem].append(fromitem)
        # Convert the dict-function to the desired list of lists
        alist = [[toitem] + fromitems
                 for toitem, fromitems in afunction.items()]
        # Store that list form of the function
        result.append(alist)
    return result


for item in functions_as_lists(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['x', 'y']):
    print(item)
```

The output from that is:

```
[['a', 'x', 'y']]
[['a', 'x'], ['b', 'y']]
[['a', 'x'], ['c', 'y']]
[['a', 'x'], ['d', 'y']]
[['b', 'x'], ['a', 'y']]
[['b', 'x', 'y']]
[['b', 'x'], ['c', 'y']]
[['b', 'x'], ['d', 'y']]
[['c', 'x'], ['a', 'y']]
[['c', 'x'], ['b', 'y']]
[['c', 'x', 'y']]
[['c', 'x'], ['d', 'y']]
[['d', 'x'], ['a', 'y']]
[['d', 'x'], ['b', 'y']]
[['d', 'x'], ['c', 'y']]
[['d', 'x', 'y']]
```

My code uses a `defaultdict` which, in CPython 3.7, preserves order. That may not be true in other distributions, so my code may result in lines that are a bit different from the output above. More complicated code in Python 3.6 and above could use a regular `dict` rather than a `defaultdict` which would solve that.

Note: If you really want the first line to be `['a', 'x', 'y']` rather than `[['a', 'x', 'y']]`, you could add these two lines just after the line that defines the variable `alist`:

```
if len(alist) == 1:
    alist = alist[0]
```

But that probably is not what you want for longer values of `list_a`.

Answer (score 0):

If am not sure if I understand your algorithm. But at least it works for your instance.

Suppose list_b = [0,1,2 ...] so that it will be easy to understand.
Your example can be regarded as:

```
['a', 'a']   # [x->'a', y->'a']
['a', 'b']   # [x->'a', y->'b']
['a', 'c']   # [x->'a', y->'c']
...
['d', 'c']   # [x->'d', y->'c']
```

So you can use

```
len_b = len(list_b)
itertools.permutations(list_a, len_b)
```

In this instance there will be 12 items, and `['a','a'], ['b','b'],...` will not be generated by permutations becuase it is "with_replacement", which can be problematic.

In python (and also in math), permutation is position sensitive and repetitive item is not allowed. Although combinition allows replacement, it is position insensitive.

So why your requirement is special is that it is permutation with replacement. Very intesting but I am afraid I cannot solve it now.

It will be difficult to deal when `list_b` becomes large. For example if `list_b=[i,j,k,l]`, we should consider

```
[a,a,b,c]  #[i->a, j->a, k->b, l->c]
[a,b,a,c]  #[i->a, j->b, k->a, l->c]
[a,b,c,a]  #[i->a, j->b, k->c, l->a]
```

It is neither permutation nor combination.